# widget_service_trigger_update() return WIDGET_ERROR_PERMISSION_DENIED error

Tags: widget, native, tizen

I'm developing native widget application in Tizen.
I want to update a widget application from UI application.

So, I find widget_service_trigger_update() API to update native widget.
But widget_service_trigger_update() return WIDGET_ERROR_PERMISSION_DENIED error.

Tell me what I did something wrong please.

Comment: which way you follow for communication between widget and UI app? message port or Data directory or sqlite or via service app ?

Comment: Thank you for comment. But widget application can have multiple instances and widget_service_trigger_update() can update a specific widget instance by widget id. So, I think it is easy way to widget instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a something important.
The widget application and UI application should be packaged together.

When UI application which are not packaged with widget application use widget_service_trigger_update(), API return 'WIDGET_ERROR_PERMISSION_DENIED'.

I verified to work well in same package. :)

Good Luck.